# Django drf requests seem to be restarting when taking a long time

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django with DRF and I have a viewset that writes info to a csv file and then sends the link to the user.

The function works correctly when the data retrieved is not too big, so when the response time is reasonable everything works ok.

The problem is when the request takes a longer time. It seems like it simply restarts from the request call all by itself

```
    def get_operations(self, request):
        logger.info("Starting export request...")
   #[...business logic to retrive the data ...]
        file_url = settings.MEDIA_PREFIX_PATH + file_path
        logger.info("Saving response in %s", file_absolute_path)
        f = open(file_absolute_path, "w+")
        all_operations = operations.all()
        i = 0
        for operation in all_operations:
            i = i + 1
            #code to show progress in the log
            if (i / len(all_operations)*1000) % 5 == 0:
                logger.info("Progress:  %d ", (i / len(all_operations)*100))

            f.write("%s,%d,%d,%d,%s,%s\n" % (operation.datetime, operation.amount, operation.field2, operation.field3, operation.field5, operation.field6))
        logger.info("Response saved, sending link %s", file_url)
        return Response(file_url)
```

In the log, this is what I'm getting

```
INFO 2018-11-26 11:23:33,525 Starting export request...
INFO 2018-11-26 11:23:34,223 Response retrieved : 17010 records
INFO 2018-11-26 11:23:34,225 Saving response in /tmp/generated_csv/1543231414.2250094.csv
INFO 2018-11-26 11:23:42,825 Progress:  10 
INFO 2018-11-26 11:23:51,161 Progress:  20 
INFO 2018-11-26 11:23:59,072 Progress:  30 
INFO 2018-11-26 11:24:07,694 Starting export request...
INFO 2018-11-26 11:24:08,346 Response retrieved : 17010 records
INFO 2018-11-26 11:24:08,348 Saving response in /tmp/generated_csv/1543231448.3486001.csv
INFO 2018-11-26 11:24:16,653 Progress:  10 
INFO 2018-11-26 11:24:24,271 Progress:  20 
INFO 2018-11-26 11:24:32,248 Progress:  30 
INFO 2018-11-26 11:24:42,573 Starting export request...
INFO 2018-11-26 11:24:44,101 Response retrieved : 17010 records
INFO 2018-11-26 11:24:44,109 Saving response in /tmp/generated_csv/1543231484.1097722.csv
INFO 2018-11-26 11:24:55,092 Progress:  10 
INFO 2018-11-26 11:25:04,131 Progress:  20 
INFO 2018-11-26 11:25:11,242 Progress:  30 
INFO 2018-11-26 11:25:16,801 Starting export request...
INFO 2018-11-26 11:25:17,499 Response retrieved : 17010 records
INFO 2018-11-26 11:25:17,501 Saving response in /tmp/generated_csv/1543231517.5013359.csv
```

I'm sure that the issue is not from the client side, because i also tried it with postman.

I just don't understand what can cause the request to be called all by itself.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't help much with this question in its current form. Try to see what you get from the web server log (apache or nginx). They may try to process the request again or maybe your client does. Try to tune their timeout. Some will close connection if the request hasn't been processed in a configured timeframe

Comment: No idea what's causing restarts, but you definitely need to optimize this process. It's too slow. My guess is that "progress logging" considerably influences performance. I use similar approach in one of the projects, where about 1 million records are written to CSV and the whole process takes about as much time as your 30 % with 17k records. I'm also querying in chunks but that shouldn't matter with 17k records.

Comment: @Linovia, I'm using gunicorn, I'll try to search in gunicorn if this is something common there

Comment: @Borut the progress log was just added to debug the issue, it happens even without it, can there be another reason that makes the writing slow ?

Comment: I see, @DanyY. Try rewriting the CSV writing process by using "with". By using "with" it's predictable when data will be saved to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing its not a problem from Django or DRF, most probably its an issue with `gunicorn` or something which you are using to serve Django. So instead of doing this big file operations in synchronous mode, try any asynchronous process. For example:

```
import threading 

...

def process_file(self, file_absolute_path, all_operations):
        f = open(file_absolute_path, "w+")
        i = 0
        for operation in all_operations:
            i = i + 1
            # it will be visible in your logger file, so you can see the progress
            if (i / len(all_operations)*1000) % 5 == 0:
                logger.info("Progress:  %d ", (i / len(all_operations)*100))
                f.write("%s,%d,%d,%d,%s,%s\n" % (operation.datetime, operation.amount, operation.field2, operation.field3, operation.field5, operation.field6))

def get_operations(self, request):
    logger.info("Starting export request...")
    all_operations = operations.all()
    file_url = settings.MEDIA_PREFIX_PATH + file_path
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.process_file,
                         args=(file_absolute_path, all_operations))
    t.start()
    logger.info("Saving response in %s", file_absolute_path)
    logger.info("Response saved, sending link %s", file_url)
    return Response(file_url)
```

Here I have given example using Python's [Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). But you can use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for this purpose as well(and its a better solution).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this, I'll just have the issue that the link i sent is empty until the async task finishes.
Maybe I should send other requests to check that the file finished to send back the link ? Is there a best practice for this ?

Comment: You can send an email with the link later. Just send a message to user that his link will be sent shortly.